# Add customer store view wise

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, multistore, customer-account

I am working on multi store website.I want to add customer store view wise because at present my customres login from any store view but i want to restrict to store views.How it is possible?

Comment: Theoretically, customers should not be restricted at store-view level, concept of store-views suggests that a customer registered at any store should be able to access other store-views. If you have to, I'd suggest considering second website instead of store-views(or stores).

Comment: But how we can restrict a customer which are using store A view not login into Store B view

Comment: If your business logic really wants that scenario, I'd suggest creating website A and Website B, instead of Store A and Store B.

Comment: But i want with Store A and Store B. How can i do this.

Comment: It wouldn't be possible out of the box in Magento, you'll need to modify the scope of customer entity. If you know how EAV entities work, you can try your luck with that, otherwise I'd suggest searching for something pre-build for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> System => configuration

Select

> Customer Configuration under Customers tab.

There you can make Share Customer Accounts to Per website rather than Global.
http://prntscr.com/8nw5fq

Comment: Yes i am using per website setting but i want customer for "Store Views".

Comment: If you have to limit per Store, then you will need a module to introduce that.